# How to scale the scene relative to an objects metric values?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, objects, scale, measurement

I have created an office desk in Cycles and am very pleased with the result and how it appears to the eye.

It is only now that I have changed the scale to the metric system and want to **re-scale the table plate** with metric values - so that it stays true to the real world measurements but at the same time, ***having the rest of the table*** (scene) **change its values accordingly**.

I had hoped there is a way to accomplish that without having to refit every piece by hand.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Congrats on the result. Scale is unit-less. Put simply a scale of 2 means twice as big in any unit. Changing the blender unit to metric, and the unit scale factor, changes only the displayed value of properties with a dimension eg  length and volume for example.   Can you elaborate with a screen shot or two what you are trying to achieve?  It sounds like you could simply adjust the unit scale factor.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find any answer right now.</sup>

Scale all objects simultaneously towards a common center (the 3D cursor).

1. Position the 3D cursor at the common center. This can simply be the origin of the scene. To place the 3D cursor at the scene origin (0, 0, 0), press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and select *Cursor to Center*.
2. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> select the objects you wish to rescale.
   Note, that the dimension values take all selected objects into account not just the active one.
3. Set the 3D cursor as the pivot point with the shortcut <kbd>NumpadPeriod</kbd> or via the 3D view's menu.
   [image]
4. Rescale with <kbd>S</kbd>, then enter the desired value (e.g. *0.01*) and press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> to confirm.
   *You will have to calculate this value beforehand by dividing the desired measurement with the current measure. E.g. If you table has a dimension[0] of 1.5 and you want it to be 2, your scaling value will be `2 / 1.5 = 1.333`. This can be done during the scaling operation.*
   *Press* <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> *and confirm with* <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Apply the scale of the objects by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and choose **Scale**.

Comment: @Pilot4007 On Stackexchange, there is "no need" for thank you comment. But if this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by checking the mark on the top left of the answer.

Comment: Was hitting enter, wanted to state my problems, sorry. I presume that in step 2. you meant RMB? With RMB I managed to scale the whole Table however I encountered further issues. The scaling values don't seem to be Metric so I dont know what value I have to enter to achieve the desired Metric Size. So I scale by mouse looking at the Metric values in the Transform Properties Demensions Tab. These differ by several centimeters when all table planes are selected (The table plate is larger than those values, how?) but since I want a fix table scale X0.6 Y1.6, how can I scale the rest accordingly?

Comment: @Pilot (Fixed the LMB > RMB). In step 4 you literally **enter** (with the keyboard) a value. I extended the answer describing the step further.

Comment: Aldding an empty at (0, 0, 0) and making it the parent of all scene objects without a parent is my usual goto for this. Scale the empty. Apply scale on empty and remove when happy with size.